# systemd-nspawn run Firefox in container without sudo

Tags: firefox, containers, systemd

I've installed a nspawn container that contains firefox. I've used the following instruction:
https://wiki.debian.org/nspawn#Firefox_example

So far it works. But i'd like to use a script and an applet-starter to run this container.

The Shell-Script:

```
sudo systemd-nspawn --setenv=DISPLAY=:0    \
                --bind-ro=/tmp/.X11-unix/    \
                --private-users=pick    \
                --private-users-chown    \
                -D /var/lib/machines/deb-firefox/    \
                --as-pid2 firefox-esr
```

If I start the script in the terminal with sudo, it works. If I call the script by the applet starter nothing happens.

What do I wrong?

Comment: From the systemd tag: Use this tag for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a curious solution, but it works. The applet starter get the following call:

```
mate-terminal -e 'sudo sh /home/ea/bin/firefox-nspawn.sh'
```